# why addressing wrong? in x86 real mode boot sector code

Tags: assembly

Get the "UV" printed in somewhere near the screen centre while "UV" supposed to be printed in the very upper-left of the screen, when trying to write two letters "UV" to the video memory (0xb8000), in the boot sector under x86 real mode using GAS AT&T assembly.

The command used:

```
as os1.s -o os1.o;ld os1.o -o os1 -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary;sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu max -drive format=raw,file=os1
```

Guessing the error is related to the addressing memory. `%bx` supposed to be the initial number 0 saved in memory `scn_pos`. While it is something near 1000. Do not know why.

```
.code16          #! tells the assembler to generate 16-bit code
.globl _start
                    #.section .data
.section .text
_start:
movw $0x0d55, %ax
call write_screen
movw $0x0d56, %ax
call write_screen
jmp .
write_screen:
    push %ds
    pushl %ebx
    mov $0xb800, %bx  #! 0xb800 changes to scn_sel at 32-bit mode
    mov %bx,%ds
    mov scn_pos, %bx
    mov %ax, (%bx) # write to screen
    add $2, %bx
    cmp $2000, %bx
    jb 1f
    mov $0, %bx
1:  mov %bx, scn_pos
    popl %ebx
    pop %ds
    ret
scn_pos:
    .word 0x0    #! needs to be 32-bit at 32-bit mode
.org 510
.word 0xAA55
```

the "UV" should be printed in the very beginning of the screen instead of at somewhere the centre of the screen.

Comment: After you change %ds, the memory read from scn_pos is performed using the new ds, so it reads some other memory location. You could use %cs:scn_pos.

Comment: A better option may be to use %es to address the screen and don’t change %ds.

Comment: @prl : Using %cs:scn_pos also has its own problems if _CS_ hasn't been set. You can't rely on CS being 0x0000 unless you perform some kind of FAR JMP (ljmp) to set it. I'd just go with using ES

Comment: @Michael, I thought of that, but for some reason I believed that the call to write_screen was already relying on the value of CS. Obviously it isn't... So, Jesse, ignore my first suggestion and use ES to address the screen.

Comment: Hi prl, Michael and all. Thanks a lot. Program now is working correctly after %es used instead of %ds. I will move on to explore more ^-^.